# How to select records with conditions in a class data.frame using R?

Tags: r

I have a data set that contains colors. I want to select the records where the colors are the same in column 8, 9, and 10.

```
  Column 8 Column 9 Column 10 
    red       blue    yellow 
    green     green   green 
    yellow    yellow  blue
```

Here is what I have so far?

```
     d1<-d[,8] # contains column 8 
     d2<-d[,9] 
     d3<-d[,10] 
     n<-191#number of rows in data set 
     i<-1#for iteration 
     for (i in 1:n){ 
        if((d1[i]==d2[i])& (d1[i]==d3[i]){ #checks if the colors match
           dl<-c(d1[i],d2[i],d3[i]))
           dl<-cat(dl, "\n")
       i<-i+1}
        else{
       i<-i+1
     }}
```

Here is some of the output:

```
6 6 6 
2 2 2 
2 2 2 
6 6 6 
2 2 2 
4 4 4 
2 2 2
```

My questions are 1) how can I make the output the colors instead of having the levels as output? 2) When I try to print the variable dl, my output changing from what I showed previously to `NULL`. Why is this?

Comment: R is not C: `d[as.character(d[,8])==as.character(d[,9]) & as.character(d[,8])==as.character(d[,10]),]` Note that your columns are of type factor, which makes things more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a couple of remarks:

- Since the desired output are colors instead of having the levels , Better here to use strings and not factors.
- use R vectorized `==` operator as mentioned in the comment.
- Using named column for subsetting safer than columns indexing.

For example:

```
    d[d[,'Column8']==d[,'Column9'] & d[,'Column8']==d[,'Column10'],]
    Column8 Column9 Column10
    2   green   green    green
```

where `d` is defined as:

```
d <- read.table(text='  Column8 Column9 Column10 
    red       blue    yellow 
    green     green   green 
    yellow    yellow  blue ',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```